# Port forwarding on a windows domain

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding

I am trying to figure out how to manage port forwarding rules on a router that acts as a gateway for a windows domain that has on it multiple web servers.

Depending on the request that comes in I need to be able to forward that request to the right web server.

Can anyone explain how this works?

Setup information so far ...

New domain controller with DNS services running on it.
DHCP handled by router (static IP's where appropriate).

The router is configured to use my domain controller as DNS server 1 and google as DNS server 2 (should the domain controller be down, normal internet traffic should still work).
My plan eventually is to have a second DNS / Domain controller running on a second physical host (not relevant though I suspect).

DNS scenarios to handle ...

```
example.com     -> public IP -> 192.168.1.5 (Web Server 1)
foo.example.com -> public IP -> 192.168.1.6 (Web Server 2)
```

Can anyone explain how I go about this so that such requests will work both inside and outside the local LAN?

Typical usage scenarios ...

```
User wanting to access Intranet site from the office / home
User wanting to access the corporate website from the office / home
```

Comment: Port forwarding works with *ports* and *routing* at the TCP/IP level, and has no knowledge of *domains* at the HTTP level. You're looking for a *reverse proxy*, which can be accomplished with some webservers like IIS or Nginx, or with more specialised load balancers like HAProxy.

Comment: @Bob is correct. You'll want the router to forward all traffic to your reverse proxy server. This server will look at what the request is (mail.example.com, foo.example.com) and forward the traffic to the appropriate internal server.

Comment: Ah ok ... so I could just push all requests in to one of the web boxes for now and have IIS handle the forwarding to the other box until I get a reverse proxy in place.

Comment: Any recommendations on reverse proxying / how to set that up right? on Microsoft servers?

Comment: Depends on your needs (number of servers, simultaneous connections, etc.) and a fair bit of it is down to opinion, but Nginx and HAProxy are both used for high-throughput load balancing by *very* large companies. IIS... not so much, but it might be the best option on Windows. But if you're here asking this question, you're probably not managing a big enough site to need anything special.